# Which is the best way to start a task in C#

Tags: c#, .net, task

Which is the best way to start a task in C# (if there are any differences?)
The ways I've found but not sure which one to use:

```
//Using run
Task.Run(()=> MyMethod());

//Using factory
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod(); });

//Using action
Task task = new Task(new Action(MyMethod));
task.Start();

//Using lambda
Task task = new Task(() => MyMethod() );
task.Start();


private void MyMethod()
{
   //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: `Task.Run()` is the way to start a task properly. You should never use `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: @CallumLinington Explaining why would be better.

Comment: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

Comment: @Nasreddine I would do, but there are so many answer on stackoverflow for it.

Comment: @CallumLinington, 'should never' until you need explicitly set `TaskScheduler`?

Comment: @pkuderov the default one is sufficient in most scenarios, so for the OP he should just use `Run`

Comment: Thank you @CallumLinington @Nasreddine! I will go with new Task. One question, Is the lambda or action a way to go or should I use something else?

Comment: Why `new Task`... `Task.Run` surely... Whether you use an action delegate a func delegate or method as the delegate it doesn't matter. It purely depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CallumLinington Yes, Task.Run. Thank you for the response